# How to include <T as Trait>::Blocknumber in a struct within a Substrate FRAME pallet

Tags: rust, substrate

Can anybody tell me please how to include `<T as Trait>::BlockNumber` and `<T as Trait>::AccountId` in my struct within my pallet module?

My current solution is to add a generic parameter T with a Trait bound to "Trait". [Link to code](https://github.com/sea212/superorganism/blob/162d1232d405960f7924a05e237eed9c7744b417/pallets/community_identity/src/lib.rs#L31-L42).

I think the usage of that generic struct as a function parameter type in `decl_module!` (line 72) does lead to the following error:

> error[E0277]: `T` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
>
> -- snip --
>
> = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `T`
>
> = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `PhysicalProof<T, [u8; 32]>`
>
> = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `(PhysicalProof<T, [u8; 32]>,)`
>
> = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
>
> = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
>
> help: consider further restricting this bound
>
> impl<$trait_instance: $trait_name + std::fmt::Debug $(, $instance: $instantiable)?> $crate::dispatch::fmt::Debug

I have tried to implement `fmt::Debug` manually for T within that struct, but either that is not a solution or I am incapable of doing it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion from [Guillaume](https://matrix.to/#/@guillaume:matrix.parity.io) from [substrate-technical Element chat](https://matrix.to/#/!HzySYSaIhtyWrwiwEV:matrix.org/$160442716457620HRwSF:matrix.parity.io?via=matrix.parity.io&via=corepaper.org&via=matrix.org) that solved the problem:

> in rust the code:
>
> ```rust
> /// Structure that contains the proof
> #[derive(Debug)]
> pub struct PhysicalProof<T, ProofData> where
>   ProofData: Codec + Clone + Debug + Decode + Encode + Eq + PartialEq,
>   T: Trait,
> {
>   proof: ProofData,
>   date: T::BlockNumber,
> }
> ```
>
> Will do `impl<..> Debug for PhysicalPool<...> where ..., ProofData: Debug, T: Debug` this additional bounds are unwanted in your situation, but rust add them anyway.
> Thus when you try to use the stuct it says it doesn't implement Debug because T doesn't implement Debug.
>
> One solution is to implmeent manually, another one would be to do:
>
> ```
> /// Structure that contains the proof
> #[derive(Debug)]
> pub struct PhysicalProof<BlockNumber ProofData> where
>   ProofData: Codec + Clone + Debug + Decode + Encode + Eq + PartialEq, BLockNumber: ...
> {
>   proof: ProofData,
>   date: BlockNumber,
> }
> ```

Comment: Removing `T` and adding `BlockNumber` as a generic has one disadvantage in my opinion: Since `BlockNumber` cannot be imported directly, the trait bounds have to be copied from the crate that declares `BlockNumber`. By doing so, any future updates to the type are not reflected in the struct. For this reason I decided to implement a rudimentary Debug trait for the struct that covers `T`.

Comment: Is that not the exact same thing I explained in my answer?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed I think the solutions differ a bit. Your answer is generally correct and was well explained, thank you for taking your time to explain it that clear. In the context of Substrate, the implementation of Trait that is used by the pallet is generated by macros and cannot be modified directly. In this scenario, the solutions that were suggested by Guillaume can be applied: Either use the BlockNumber, which is a type within Trait that has a Debug trait bound, or implement the Debug trait for the PhysicalProof struct. I am still a beginner. Substrate experts, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

To derive `Debug` for as struct, all of its fields must be able to implement `Debug`. Right now, the compiler doesn't know if `T` is debuggable.

You can tell the compiler that `T` implements `Debug` by adding a `Debug` as a bound for type `T`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct PhysicalProof<T, ProofData> where
    // `T` must implement `Debug`   
    T: Trait + Debug,
{
    proof: ProofData,
    date: T::BlockNumber,
}
```